# How to display videos from xml url for windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Hi am using xml file given below,how can i get videos from xml file?

```
     <videourl>
      <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/52375409?fullscreen=0" width="500"   height="298" frameborder="0"></iframe>
     </videourl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get video Url

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load("Xml.xml");
string url=(string)rootElement.Elements("iframe").Single().Attribute("src").Value;
```

Comment: i hope your answer thank you so much.,

Comment: hi i got null references value.,